# Trying to fill remaining space next to vertical fixed div with fluid dimensions

Tags: html, css, fixed, fluid-layout, minmax

I have a vertical fixed div on the left with a min/max width set and 100% height. I can't seem to fill the remaining space without overlapping. Any solutions?

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#leftBanner {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #CCC;
    width: 22%;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 245px;
    max-width: 355px;
    float:left;
}

#mainContent {
    width: auto;
    height: 2000px;
    background-color: red;
    opacity: .3;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="leftBanner"></div>

<div id="mainContent">asdf</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yfJp2/)

I've been experimenting with a wrapper around the two divs but still having trouble. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: the fiddle looks fine to me. what's the problem?

Comment: I don't want the #mainContent to overlap the #leftBanner, which is what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I placed the min/max fluid div inside the content div and covered it up with a fixed div of the same dimensions. Thanks for all your quick responses. Here's the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/T52Ms/

(The code below is all in the fiddle.)

CSS

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#container{
width:100%;

}
#leftBanner {
height: 100%;
background-color: #CCC;
width: 22%;
min-width: 245px;
max-width: 355px;
float:left;
}
#fixedBanner {
height: 100%;
background-color: blue;
width: 22%;
min-width: 245px;
max-width: 355px;
float:left;
z-index: 9999;
position: fixed;
}
#mainContent {
height: 2000px;
opacity: .3;
float:right;
width: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">


<div id="fixedBanner">Main Banner</div>


<div id="mainContent">  



<div id="leftBanner">asdf</div> <!-- end leftBanner -->



asdf</div><!-- end mainContent -->
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't just set width: auto; and have it fill the rest of the space, because that element doesn't have a relationship to the other div.

One solution for this problem is to use a grid layout. Where you have a container that is width: 100%; and then it's children are a percentage of that.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/cJvJ6/4/)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="column one">one tenth</div>
    <div class="column nine">nine tenth</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.one{
    width: 10%;
    background-color: red;
}
.nine{
    width: 90%;
    background-color: grey;
}
.column{
    height: 100px;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: I understand how the auto width works, I was just experimenting with a few different ways to work this out when I posted my code. Either way, this solution does not work with a min/max width on the fixed column div, which is the problem I am having.

Comment: @DBowman You're putting a min / max width on the children. You can't have width: 22% and then tell it to only be between 200px and 300px. That's not how it works. You have to put the min/max on the parent.

Comment: Edit: That's not how it works when you want the second div to fill up the space. You would have to give it a width of 78% and then give it a min/max as well*

Comment: My code has no parent element. I'm still trying to work this out. But your solution is not relative to my the problem I am having.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a good reason to have all three of these:

```
width: 22%;
min-width: 245px;
max-width: 355px;
```

That doesn't seem particularly responsive, with it only varying by 90px.  If you can make your left bar a fixed width, say 245px, then you could add

```
margin-left:245px;
```

to the right bar.

Comment: I would like to keep them, yes. I know that this could be easily achieved without those elements. I'm asking because I would like to find a way to keep them.

Comment: My *assumption* is that javascript is the only solution, unless you could use any graphical tricks to fake the appearance for your needs (eg set a page background colour the same as the right div colour and have a left margin the same as the max-width).

Comment: I agree with this answer, remove the min/max width and just make it static.  You can still use responsive design to have different left column widths, but it wouldn't be as "fluid" as it is with min/max and a percentage width.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you will need javascript if you want the #mainContent to have the rest of the page side filled. The overlapping is caused by the position:fixed style. I don't think you will need float:left in this case.

Anyway if you want to keep the position:fixed, the min/max width and the #mainContent's auto filling width, then probably you should use some javascript (jQuery will do) and calculate on initialize and resize the #leftBanner width and the remaing window with so that you can give your #mainContent div the right width and margin-left/padding-left or just left (with position:absolute).

Just to be clear I am not saying that there isn't simpler solution, I just didn't find.